# Keras tensors - Get values with indices coming from another tensor

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, slice, tensor

Suppose I have these two tensors:

- `valueMatrix`, shaped as `(?, 3)`, where `?` is the batch size
- `indexMatrix`, shaped as `(?, 1)`

I want to retrieve values from `valueMatrix` at the indices contained in `indexMatrix`.

Example (pseudocode):

```
valueMatrix = [[7,15,5],[4,6,8]] -- shape=(2,3) -- type=float 
indexMatrix = [[1],[0]] -- shape = (2,1) -- type=int
```

I want from this example to do something like:

```
valueMatrix[indexMatrix] --> returns --> [[15],[4]]
```

---

I prefer Tensorflow over other backends, but the answer must be compatible with a Keras model using Lambda layers or other suitable layers for the task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import tensorflow as tf
valueMatrix = tf.constant([[7,15,5],[4,6,8]])
indexMatrix = tf.constant([[1],[0]])

# create the row index with tf.range
row_idx = tf.reshape(tf.range(indexMatrix.shape[0]), (-1,1))
# stack with column index
idx = tf.stack([row_idx, indexMatrix], axis=-1)
# extract the elements with gather_nd
values = tf.gather_nd(valueMatrix, idx)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(values))
#[[15]
# [ 4]]
```

Comment: Great! Thank you -- I couldn't find a keras replacement for `tf.gather_nd`, but it will work anyway inside a lambda layer.