# How could I get part of a tensor with indices coming from another tensor? (Keras, tf backend)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, slice, tensor

I am working with RNN and attention mechanisms.

Different from soft attention (which weights time steps of RNN by attention tensor and sum up them), I want to select the most `k` important time steps and using other methods to combine them.

Thus, I have three tensors:

- `RNNMatrix`,  with shape `(None, time_steps, cell_num)`, where `None` is the batch size
- `AttMatrix`,  with shape `(None, time_steps)`
- `IdxMatrix`, with shape `(None, k)`, each row is the index of the most k important time steps, get from `AttMatrix`

Ideally, I can get `KRNNMatrix` shaped `(None, k, cell_num)` through `RNNMatrix` and `IdxMatrix`.

The straightforward method to get `IdxMatrix` is using `tf.nn.top_k`. My code below:

```
selected_att_num = 10

def My_select_layer(ip, k_num):

    LSTM_out = ip[0]
    Attention = ip[1]

    idx = tf.nn.top_k(Attention, k=k_num, sorted = True).indices

    # gen row index
    row_idx = tf.range(tf.shape(Attention)[0])

    # repeat k times
    row_idx_repeat = tf.keras.backend.repeat(tf.reshape(row_idx,(-1,1)), k_num)

    # gen index for gather_nd
    row_idx_repeat_reshape = tf.reshape(row_idx_repeat, (-1,k_num))
    idx_stacked = tf.stack([row_idx_repeat_reshape, idx], axis=-1)

    return tf.gather_nd(LSTM_out, idx_stacked)


_input = Input(shape = (data_length, data_dim))
LSTM_out = LSTM(cells, return_sequences=True)(_input )

# compute att for each step
Attention = Activation('tanh')(LSTM_out)
Attention = Dense(1, use_bias=False)(Attention)
Attention = Flatten()(Attention)
Attention = Activation('softmax', name='attention')(Attention)

LSTM_out_gathered = Lambda(My_select_layer,arguments={'k_num':selected_att_num})([LSTM_out , Attention])
```

The model complies well and throws an error when I train it:

ValueError: An operation has `None` for gradient. Please make sure that all of your ops have a gradient defined (i.e. are differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, K.round, K.eval.

I'm pretty sure this error blame to my Lambda layer, most probably blame to the variable `indices` of `tf.nn.top_k`.

But I don't know how to fix it.

Or, is the operation *'select tensor by index'* theoretically nondifferentiable? If so, is there any workaround?
In the worst case, could reinforcement learning hold this?

I also search a lot on the internet and find a very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46526869/keras-tensors-get-values-with-indices-coming-from-another-tensor/46527020#46527020) asked by Daniel Möller. However, Daniel does not show more details about how he solves this problem.